# Proving the Triangle Inequality Using the Law of Cosines

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors

The question is as follows:

> Use the vector form of the Law of Cosines to show that $|u + v|^2 \le (u + v)^2$ holds for any vectors **u** and **v**. What does this prove?

I know that the vector form of the Law of Cosines is $\cos(C) = \frac{u \cdot v}{|u||v|}$, but I don't know how to derive $|u + v|^2 \le (u + v)^2$ from it. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what does $w^2$ means if $w$ is a vector?

Comment: When vector $w$ is placed tail-to-tail with vector $w$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\;\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}\;$ be two non-zero vectors and let
 $\;u := |\mathbf{u}|,\;v := |\mathbf{v}|.\;$ Then $(u+v)^2=u^2+v^2+2uv,\;$
 $\;|\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}|^2 = (\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})\cdot(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})=
\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}+2\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}=
u^2+v^2+2\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v},\;$ and $\cos(C)\le1,$
and since $\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v} = \cos(C)uv,\;$ we have 
$\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}<uv.\;$ Finally, $|\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}|^2\le(u+v)^2.$
If $\mathbf{w}:=\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v},\;$ $w:=|\mathbf{w}|,\;$ then taking square roots gives $\;w\le u+v\;$ which is the famous [Triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).